# Use JavaScript to show list of random number and display it on Modal

Tags: javascript, html

I have JavaScript coding that will generate the  random number and now I would like to show the random number on the modal each time I click the submit button. Where show I to put the random number variable in order to show on the modal?

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){$("#mybtn").click(function(){
       $("#myModal").modal();
       $('#company').html($('#company').val());
       
     function randomNumber(min, max) {  
    min = Math.ceil(min); 
    max = Math.floor(max); 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
}  
//// I want to show it on the modal it will display the company name and random number
document.write( randomNumber(9551008730006, 9551008730100) );
    });
     $("#myModal").modal("hide").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {        
        location.reload();                   
    }); 
</script>
```

```html
<form id="inputform" type="text" method="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="company">Company Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ABC Bakers" id="company" readonly>
        </div>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="prefix">Company Prefix</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="1234" id="prefix" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            <label for="InputFile">Product Image input</label>
            <input type="file" id="InputFile" required>
    </div><button input type="button" name="btn" value="Submit" id="mybtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit">Submit</button> 

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-submit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Hello</h4><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button></div><div class="modal-body"> 
              <h4 id="company">  </h4>Thank You for your submission! Your <br id="randomnum">. Please check your product information.</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following js to show the random number on contact and randomnum

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function randomNumber(min, max) {  
        min = Math.ceil(min); 
        max = Math.floor(max); 
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
    }
    $("#mybtn").click(function(){
       $("#myModal").modal();
       var randomNo = randomNumber(9551008730006, 9551008730100)
       $('#company').html(randomNo);                       
       $('#randomnum').html(randomNo);
    });
    $("#myModal").modal("hide").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {        
        location.reload();                   
    }); 
</script>
```